# How can I set size for JLabel or JButton as the maximum length of the content?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

How to add a `jLabel` to the last position in jPanel?

I want to insert a `Jlabel` into the last position of a `Jpanel`. When another `Jlabel` is inserted into it will be in the last position and the old Jlabel will be moved upwards. Like messaging with Messenger.

```
//Create a message jlabel
JLabel message = createInnerPanel(messageContent); 
//Code I want right here
panel.add(message);
panel.invalidate();
panel.validate();
panel.repaint();
```

[image: It is similar to messaging apps]

I used `setBound()` but I think it isn't useful when the chat frame has many messages and `BorderLayout` is inactive

Sorry if my English is not good.

Thanks so much, wish the best for you.

Moreover, I wanna ask what should I use to contain these messages. When the `jPanel` have many messages it cannot scroll to see the old messages.

Comment: Use an appropriate layout, something like a BoxLayout with Y_AXIS policy, and then embed the whole into a ScrollPane.

Comment: I would probably consider using something like a [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), but you'd probably need a custom look and feel to make it post content from the bottom instead of the top

Comment: *"When the jPanel have many messages it cannot scroll to see the old messages."* - wrap the `JPanel` in `JScrollPane`

Answer (score 0):

> When another Jlabel is inserted into it will be in the last position and the old Jlabel will be moved upwards

You can use a `Box`, which is really a convenience class for a `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout`. The first component should be "glue" so all components are shifted to the bottom:

```
Box messagePanel = new Box.createVerticalBox();
messagePanel.add( Box.createGlue() );
```

You will also need to tell the label to be aligned to the right in the panel:

```
JLabel message = new JLabel("...");
message.setAlignmentX(SwingConstants.TRAILING);
messagePanel.add( message );
```

Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.

The tutorial also contains a section on using scroll panes.

Answer (score -1):

I think instead of using JLabel, you can use JEditorPane because if you have long text in JLabel, it will not wrap text to the second line, moreover adding JscrollPane will make it easy to move up and down!

Take look at this snippet of code and hopefully will help you to resolve your problem.

```
   public class ChatBox {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatBox cw = new ChatBox();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                cw.buildGui();
            }
        });

    }

    public void buildGui() {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

        Container container = jFrame.getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 0;

        JEditorPane textPane = new JEditorPane();
        textPane.setEnabled(false);
        textPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
        textPane.setContentType("text/plain");


        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textPane,
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


        container.add(scrollPane, c);


        JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();

        // In case a user press enter, it will add the text to jeditorpane
        jTextField.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String message = jTextField.getText();
                jTextField.setText("");
                addText(textPane, jFrame, message);
            }
        });
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0);
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        c.gridy++;

        container.add(jTextField, c);

        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        sendButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String message = jTextField.getText();
                jTextField.setText("");
                addText(textPane, jFrame, message);
            }
        });
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10);
        c.gridx = 4;

        c.weightx = 0.1;
        sendButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65, 20));
        container.add(sendButton, c);


        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setResizable(false);
        jFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(370, 350));
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addText(JEditorPane jEditorPane, JFrame jFrame, String message) {
        try {
            // Saving the old message from jEditorPane
            String text = jEditorPane.getText();
            // Clear all
            jEditorPane.setText("");

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            //Append new lines to show the text in the lower left of the corner
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                stringBuilder.append('\n');
            stringBuilder.append(text);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
            Document doc = jEditorPane.getDocument();

            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), stringBuilder.toString(), new SimpleAttributeSet());
            doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), message, new SimpleAttributeSet());
            jFrame.repaint();
        } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jFrame, "Obs,something went wrong sorry " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as unclear as the question is: this doesn't look anywhere near the intended outcome, why do you think it helps to have the texts left/right aligned (for different types of messages, f.i.)? Also there are obvious problems, in no particular orders: a) don't hard-code sizing hints b) don't fix the size of a window (users typically get annoyed) c) replacing complete text on every addition d) adding empty lines (why?) e) frame repaint is .. not needed (as in utter nonsense) f) .. could it be that this code is written by a chatqpt?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! This code is not written by chatGPT but I tried to give him an example of how to resolve the problem! The text alignment Left or right is not the problem but I am not sure how to calculate the window size, I'll appreciate your help if you provide me with more information about it and improve my code!

Comment: thanks for the info, naturally I take your word for it :) Intention to help is good, spreading faulty code is not. Using an EditorPane (vs. individual Labels) is an interesting idea and certainly doable - but: the output should be at least _near_ the image in the question plus using editorPane api correctly (aside from not having all the errors already listed in my first comment). btw: _calculate the window size_ is a completely wrong track. There are tons of tutorials to learn from, see the swing tag wiki for references :)